Aspire: Url not showing under endpoints
I have added .NET Aspire to my ASP.NET Core Web API (with Swagger) and everything compiles fine.
But when starting the app everything seems to be working fine, except I see no url under endpoints in the dashboard. So, I can't browse to the SwaggerUI of my API.
My program.cs (APPHOST):
var builder = DistributedApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.AddProject<Projects.API>("api", launchProfileName: "IIS Express");
builder.Build().Run();

launchSettings.json (APPHOST):
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:17025;http://localhost:15225",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "DOTNET_DASHBOARD_OTLP_ENDPOINT_URL": "https://localhost:21274",
        "DOTNET_RESOURCE_SERVICE_ENDPOINT_URL": "https://localhost:22163"
      }
    },
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:15225",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "DOTNET_DASHBOARD_OTLP_ENDPOINT_URL": "http://localhost:19144",
        "DOTNET_RESOURCE_SERVICE_ENDPOINT_URL": "http://localhost:20276"
      }
    }
  }
}

launchSettings.json (API):
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iis": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:44379/swagger/index.html",
      "sslPort": 0
    },
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:55448",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "nativeDebugging": false
    },
    "API": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}


It doesn't look like you're adding SwaggerUI to the builder in Program.cs.
Try this:
var builder = DistributedApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.AddProject<Projects.API>("api", launchProfileName: "IIS Express");
var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.Run();

Hope this helps!

Hi Sam, thanks for your reply. I have replaced my code with yours but it doesn't compile. I have added this in my program.cs (AppHost). The error is: Error (active) CS1061 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddSwaggerGen' and no accessible extension method 'AddSwaggerGen'. BTW in my API i have added swagger: services.AddSwaggerConfig(Configuration);

When starting only the Api swagger works fine.

Could you please share your project's swagger related codes? It seems you don't have installed the package  Swashbuckle.AspNetCore by using the Install-Package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore -Version 6.6.2.
